# How to build children of a nested form in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, nested-forms

I know how to build the 2nd object in a controller but how do you build a third or a fourth?

In my case i need to build 3.

```
Location - has_many :product_dates, :products
ProductDate - has_many :products & belongs_to :location
Product - belongs_to :location, :product_date
```

I build the Location and Product Date easily:

```
def new
  @location = Location.new
  @location.product_dates.build
end
```

Now i need to build the products on the form. Can anyone show me how to do this?

**EDIT: Complete Answer:**

```
def new
    @location = Location.new
    product_date = @location.product_dates.build
    product_date.products.build
end

    <%= form_for @location do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :business %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>

    <%= f.fields_for :product_dates do |date| %>
    <%= date.date_select :date %>

    <%= date.fields_for :products do |product| %>
    <%= product.text_field :name %>
     <%= product.text_field :price %>
    <%= product.text_field :tag_list %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>        
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll learn everything [in video here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

EDIT:

change the nested part with:

```
<%= f.fields_for :product_dates do |date| %>
  <%= date.date_select :date %>
  <%= date.fields_for :products do |product| %>
   <%= product.text_field :name %>
   <%= product.text_field :price %>
   <%= product.text_field :tag_list %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Because `products` are nested inside `product_dates`

Comment: But it uses the "times" ability, i don't need that, i just need one instance for each.

Comment: Then don't loop, and remove `times` :)

Comment: How do you not loop? I don't understand what looping is.

Comment: `3.times {}` is a loop: the code between curly braces will be executed 3 times. So if you remove it, it will only be executed once.

Comment: OK in the console it does work but i don't see it on the form. Check out my Edit.

Comment: Check it now. Was just updating as you typed. :P

Answer (score 2):

add to your controller:

```
def new
  @location = Location.new
  @product_dates = @location.product_dates.build
  @product = @product_dates.product.build
end
```

in you ProductDate model:

```
class ProductDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
...
```

in you Location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_dates
...
```

And you form should be like this:

```
<% f.fields_for :product_dates do |date| %>
  <%= date.text_field :content %>
  <% date.fields_for :products do |product| %>
    <%= product.text_field :content %>
  <%end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: for anybody now wanting to show the existing dates, you can add an if statement which tests whether it is a new record.